# Python Web crawler, print only link that contains certain word in it's path - Mechanize, Beautiful Soup etc

Tags: python, web-crawler

So I have a web crawler which prints out all the links from given sites without repeating of same links. my code (with imported but not yet used libraries) looks like this:

```
import urllib
import re
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse
import cookielib
from urlparse import urlsplit
from publicsuffix import PublicSuffixList

url = "http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de"

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
page = br.open(url, timeout=5)

htmlcontent = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent)

newurlArray = []

for link in br.links(text_regex=re.compile('^((?!IMG).)*$')):
    newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
    if newurl not in newurlArray:
        newurlArray.append(newurl)
        print newurl
```

and it gaves me results like this:

```
.....

http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/amalgamentfernung.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/homoeopathie.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/veneers.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/prophylaxe.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/bleaching/bleaching-zahnschmuck.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/dental_wellness_care.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/digitales-roentgen.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/anfahrt.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/kontakt.html
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/impressum.html

etc....
```

Now my question is how can I tell to my program that it prints out only that link which contains word `kontakt` for example.

Should I use a regular expression for that or something else?

I've never done that so I don't know what to use to get only result:

```
http://www.zahnarztpraxis-uwe-krause.de/pages/kontakt.html
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's as easy as using a regex or plain old Python string `find()` on link.url. (EDIT: you can also use `'kontakt' in link.url` as shshank does)

```
for link in br.links(text_regex=re.compile('^((?!IMG).)*$')):

    if link.url.find('kontakt')>=0: ...do stuff on urls containing contact
    # or:
    if link.url.find('kontakt')<0: continue # skip urls without
```

Obviously both of these (string `find()` method or `in` operator) can match anywhere in the string, which is a little sloppy.
What you want to do here is only match inside the url tail.
You can check just the tail using `find()` on `link.url.split('/')[-1]`

or else `link.url.rsplit('/',2)[1]`

Answer (score 4):

why not simply do

```
if 'kontakt' in url:
    print url
else:
    continue
```

Comment: sorry, I'm python nooby so I don't know that it could be solved that easy :D